# signals and slots without dynamic memory

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a c++ signal slot framework that doesn't use dynamic memory allocation and is small. For use on MCU's in real time applications. KSignal was mentioned in another post, and is the only one I've seen so far that seems appropriate. Anyone had experience with other suitable libraries?

Comment: Since C++11 it's not that hard to come up with your own variant using e.g. [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind). You can make it "not dynamic" by using e.g. [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for a fixed number of slots.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg IIRC both `std::function` and `std::bind` can use dynamic memory.

Comment: Why do you need without dynamic memory allocation? Is there any limitation on platform where you are developing?

Comment: @doptimusprime He mentions microcontrollers and real time applications, it is common in these domains to avoid any dynamic allocation.